There is no image when using the shader in OpenTK 4.8.2
When I turn on GL.Useprogram(), then nothing is visible, only the background, and if I do not turn on the shader program, then everything is visible, though white (but this is normal)
OpenTK 4.8.2
code:
Create, Init VBO+VAO
    public void InitVAO()
    {
        VaoIndex = GL.GenVertexArray();

        GL.BindVertexArray(VaoIndex);

        _vboVertices = CreateVBO(_vertices);
        //_vboColors = CreateVBO(_colors);

        int vertexLocation = 0;

        //GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        //GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vboVertices);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
        //GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, 0);

        //GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vboColors);
        //GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, 0, 0);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
        //GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        //GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
    }

    private int CreateVBO(float[] data)
    {
        int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, data.Length * sizeof(float), data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

        return vbo;
    }

Render mesh
public void Render()
{
    GL.BindVertexArray(Mesh.VaoIndex);
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, Mesh.PolygonsCount);
}


Render calls
    public void Render()
    {
        if (_renderTargets.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        _shaderProgram.Enable();
        for (int i = 0; i < _renderTargets.Count; i++)
        {
            var renderer = _renderTargets[i];

            renderer.Render();
        }
        _shaderProgram.Disable();
    }

ShaderProgram
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

public sealed class ShaderProgram
{
    private readonly int _vertexShader;
    private readonly int _fragmentShader;
    private readonly int _program;

    public ShaderProgram(string vertexFile, string fragmentFile)
    {
        _vertexShader = CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader, vertexFile);
        _fragmentShader = CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader, fragmentFile);

        _program = GL.CreateProgram();

        GL.AttachShader(_program, _vertexShader);
        GL.AttachShader(_program, _fragmentShader);

        GL.LinkProgram(_program);

        GL.GetProgram(_program, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out int success);

        if (success != (int)All.True)
        {
            string infoLog = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(_program);
            throw new Exception(infoLog);
        }

        DeleteShader(_fragmentShader);
        DeleteShader(_vertexShader);
    }

    public void Enable() => GL.UseProgram(_program);
    public void Disable() => GL.UseProgram(0);
    public void DeleteProgram() => GL.DeleteProgram(_program);

    private void DeleteShader(int shaderIndex)
    {
        GL.DetachShader(_program, shaderIndex);
        GL.DeleteShader(shaderIndex);
    }

    private int CreateShader(ShaderType shaderType, string path)
    {
        string file = File.ReadAllText(path);
        int shaderIndex = GL.CreateShader(shaderType);

        GL.ShaderSource(shaderIndex, file);
        GL.CompileShader(shaderIndex);

        GL.GetShader(shaderIndex, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out int success);

        if (success != (int)All.True)
        {
            string infoLog = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shaderIndex);
            throw new Exception(infoLog);
        }

        return shaderIndex;
    }
}

Create window
var gameWindowSetting = new GameWindowSettings();
var nativeWindowSetting = new NativeWindowSettings()
{
    Title = "GameEngine - V3",
    ClientSize = new Vector2i(1280, 720),
    API = ContextAPI.OpenGL,
    Profile = ContextProfile.Core,
};

var screen = new Screen(gameWindowSetting, nativeWindowSetting);

screen.Run();


Vertex Shader
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}

Fragment Shader
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}

Result:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Q03HignZ.png
